# Weird buzzing noise coming from the pc (PSU perhaps)

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

Ok so this is a weird one. I'm used to troubleshooting things like this one myself, but now i'm rather stuck.

Just bought a new PC with RTX 2080 & Ryzen 7 2700X. All good, runs smooth and rather cool.
While gaming i have heard a weird buzzing noise coming from my PC. I tried to locate the sound and it seems that it might be coming from the PSU (all components are new).

Here comes the weird part: I tried reproducing it instead of having it show up randomly by stress testing my CPU and GPU at the same time. I figured if its a PSU problem while gaming then it should show up while stress testing (especially since no game has challenged my CPU & GPU at the same time so far). Ran it for about 10-15 minutes. No buzzing.

The noise can also be heard very briefly (and at a lower volume so to speak) randomly. Last night i was watching a movie, it heard a low buzz and its not the first time. Now i'm in a game (ATLAS) and SOMETIMES it starts buzzing.

Any tips on how i could troubleshoot this ? All temps are fine, no PC freeze, no BSOD, no errors at all of any kind, yet the buzzing sound is there.

I must add that i  just bought a UPS because i needed it and i also thought it might be because of my houses electricity "bouncing" (not very good at electrical stuff). Nothing changed.

I also managed to record it here -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7O7np_p6fU

You can also hear the fans, but the sound cant be missed (also a bit louder since i was recording near the source).

Any tips? Thanks!

P.S: Not sure if the `hardware-failure` tag is fine since nothing failed so far, but i'm unsure what to use.

Edit: Forgot to mention, i checked task manager while in-game when it started buzzing.  Nothing was even near 100% and my HDD was at 1% (the one the game is on).

Edit2: Added voltages.

[image]
Edit: Finally found the source of the buzzing! Its the GPU, but its not a fan. I think its the GPU case that is buzzing. After 3 days i managed to get the buzzing while my case panel was off. I tried slowing down one of the fans, the buzzing stopped while my finger was slowing the fan. Then i tried another fan, same thing. And then FINALLY i simply touched the plastic case on my GPU and the same outcome -> buzzing stopped.

From this i assume my GPU case is actually buzzing due to FAN vibrations ? My card doesnt seem to be 100% in place in the PCI slot (its rather big), but i dont think that has anything to do with it (its a not a perfect line so to speak). Any tips on how to fix the buzzing now ? I'm attaching a picture of my GPU for ref.

[image]

You can see that its not perfectly aligned if you look at the MB port.
By touching the case and it stopped i mean the grey case part on the GPU that you can see in the pic (bottom of GPU).

Comment: Think it could be a fan, making a specific noise only in a specific rpm range? Could try briefly slowing down a fan (through software if possible, or with something soft like your finger on the hub) to see if the noise changes

Comment: The only fan that could make that noise would be the PSU fan or one of the GPU fans. I've tested GPU fans by manually changing RPM and heard nothing and i did the stress test in case i can hear something if my PSU draws more power. I'll try to test the GPU fans step by step to see if i hear anything. Is there any software that can control the RPM of the PSU fan tho' ?

Comment: I haven't heard of power supply fans being easily controlled... and I'm not a fan of poking things inside a power supply (definitely not anything conductive), but maybe something "firm yet yielding" like a plastic straw would be ok for a tenth of a second...

Comment: Thats a bit too much of a risk. As you said, poking things inside a PSU is not a good idea. Perhaps someone comes with another idea for me to test. Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that the buzz is transformer laminations, and it could require a higher load before it buzzes.  Use a mechanic's stethoscope, or a piece of dowel between an item and your skull near your ear to locate sounds.  If it does seem to come from the PSU, you may need to unmount it, open it up, and confirm on the transformer inside.  The buzz is harmless, and if you fix it, you may void the warranty, so you might want to check with the manufacturer.  If knowing it's the transformer and that it's harmless is enough, don't bother messing with it.  (cont'd)

Comment: If it grates on your nerves, fixing it typically involves getting a thin, high temperature glue, lacquer, or threadlocker to wick between the laminations and dry.  Sometimes, you can just paint the outer edge with silicone or hot melt glue and it will dampen it.  If the outer edge looks completely sealed with lacquer from the manufacturer, none of these steps will make a difference.

Comment: The sound is indeed annoying, but what i'm more interested in is if it could damage my rig in any way (given the fact that i get no errors whatsoever while stress testing). I surely can't open it since it will void warranty and the problem with sending it for warranty fix is that its so hard to diagnose (mostly while gaming or randomly) that i'd probably receive it back as "no problem". Edit: If its only on higher load shouldnt it start while stress testing CPU & GPU at the same time? I literally heard nothing while doing that...

Comment: The first step is figuring out what component is making the noise.  You could try to localize it as described in the comment, but the metal case of the PSU conducts sound well, so it will be tough from the outside.  Without definitively identifying the component, people would just be guessing.  You could try contacting tech support for the PSU manufacturer and ask their advice.  As long as it's putting out all the right voltages, though, they'll probably suggest that you invest in earplugs.  :-)

Comment: BTW, if you "address" a comment to a specific user, like @fixer1234, they will receive an alert to your posting.  Otherwise, nobody will be aware of it unless they stumble across it.

Comment: @fixer1234 I assumed you get notified without tagging. Regarding voltages, as i said im not very experienced in hardware/electricity stuff. I added a pic of my voltages (from the Aorus MB software) and added warnings. The pic is from the game in which the noise shows up. I tried testing it, but in 20 minutes i only heard it about 4-5 times for 1 sec each (which is goddamn frustrating cause i cant diagnose this properly). I did get a warning at one point after stopping a stress test, but it disappeared (something about 0.6 line too low or similar). I'll keep the warnings checked and try again.

Comment: If the motherboard has a different video output like VGA or HDMI, try removing the GPU and then connecting via one of those video method and see if the noise occurs without the GPU card. If you Google "rtx 2080 buzzing noise" or something like that, you will see many people report that card making sounds. For troubleshooting at least to help pinpoint the culprit, try without that GPU and use another video output or GPU card, etc. to see if the noise occurs without that one.

Comment: First of all i would like to point that due to the nature of PSUs you should not troubleshoot on your own by unscrewing because they can sustain a deadly charge even when offline. Having said that, a PSU should not make any noice except from the fan, not even occasionally. When PSUs fail they are likely to cause damage to other components so in your place i would immediately return it and ask for a replacement. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: @JimS  I'm surely not going to open it since i'm not good at those things. I dont know how it could fail since the voltages seem fine and i have no errors (not even a freeze). Would touching the PSU while on be dangerous as well ? I thought about trying to reproduce the sound in a game and "bump" it a bit to see if the noise stops (to see if its a fan problem or not).

Comment: No its not dangerous. The issue you are facing is probably coil whine. If you are up for some troubleshooting i suggest you follow this http://forum.corsair.com/v3/showthread.php?t=85166

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend figuring out what is making the buzzing sound for starters. The most likely cause for buzzing would be the fans but as you've said, you don't think that is the case.

If the sound relates to electrical buzzing, the likely source is the Power Supply (PSU) coils. I currently have a similar intermittent problem involving coil whine which is however more whine than buzz. Where coil whine tends to be higher in pitch than what you're describing hence I don't think that's what you have.

There is a chance that something is shorting (and therefore arcing) somewhere in your computer. If you see any sparks, the part should be sent with great haste for repair or simply binned.

Having just listened to the recording, this does not sound like anything electrical, nor does it sound like coil whine. If my ears are not mistaken, that is a fan. There could be a piece of plastic in a fan somewhere, something like a zip tie perhaps?
Since it's intermittent, the offending fan may be on a temperature switch (it turns on when it gets too hot). Your main hardware is very good so it's unlikely to be that, I would check motherboard fans or other little fans that can be dotted around various components. **The PSU fan is the likeliest cause.**

**EDIT** (noise located in Graphics Card)

Look for things caught in the fan blades, or at the edges of the blades.
If that turns up empty, and the card is under warranty, I would return it.
If the card is no longer under warranty and you have the technical know how, you can attempt to locate the problem yourself by pulling apart the card. One of the fans themselves may be buzzing in which case you could try to replace it or just unplug it.

By the looks of it, your card is sagging in it's slot a great deal. This is likely what's causing the problem. For starters, you can try lying the case on it's back (such that the motherboard is facing up) which would decrease the strain on the GPU case.
If this works to stop the buzzing, you are going to need to find a way to support the gpu. These usually do the trick: [AMAZON](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01M5DCMPM/ref=asc_df_B01M5DCMPM57822019/?tag=googshopuk-21&creative=22146&creativeASIN=B01M5DCMPM&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310773493424&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=8807603790465548002&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=1006886&hvtargid=pla-455627545376)

Comment: Found the issue (or so i hope), it seems like the GPU case is buzzing. I updated my question, any tips?

Comment: I've edited my answer in light of this new information.

Comment: Not sure if this answer is what i'm looking for, but since the bounty is wearing off i think this is closest to a fix. I'll reply here again after receiving the GPU holder (ordered the CM one as i found it in my country as well) so other people can find an easier answer. Hopefully that fixes it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I hope the CM will help. I'll put the rep to good use!

Answer (score 3):

Just to remark that the RTX 2080 is a noisy card. It can also be the PSU,
but you should be able to distinguish between the two by opening the case and
listening closely.

You can hear very similar noise on YouTube in the following:

- [Rtx 2080 FE Making a very odd noise!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FMDC1sVT9DY)
- [Nvidia 2080 RTX noise issues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5LbN-bgMwgQ)

I believe that the noise is not the fans, but rather
[Coil Whine](https://www.xoticpc.com/coil-whine):

> Coil whine, also known as electromagnetically excited acoustic noise and vibration or audible magnetic noise, is one of the most frustrating phenomena in modern technology. As its name suggests, this high-pitched noise is caused by electromagnetic coils that act as inductors or transformers. Though it can come from many components, coil whine is usually found in video cards. High-end graphics cards are used to run intensive software or demanding games, which can cause them to work very hard and vibrate. Every PC component has a resonant frequency when coupled with the rest of the electrical circuit. Noise can also occur when the coil is poorly secured to the circuit board. Unfortunately, there is little you can do to reverse or remove coil whine once you have it.

This can explain why the noise is random and bears only a feint relationship
to the GPU workload, if you hit the resonance only under special conditions
and load.

If the problem is indeed Coil Whine from your video card, then your only options are:

- Better isolating your computer case,
- Changing the video card.

See also
[Tom's Hardware review](https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/nvidia-geforce-rtx-2080-founders-edition,5809-13.html)
of noise levels of the RTX 2080 in a closed case.
The average noise level was about 40 dB(A), which
[I saw](http://www.industrialnoisecontrol.com/comparative-noise-examples.htm)
being compared to urban bird calls in volume.

Comment: If its just a coil noise (as  far as i know its different from coil whine and the sound is definitely different. I had coil whine in my older GTX 970 and it sounded different). then i'm fine with it (cant change the GPU since i just bought it and cant return it). Thing is it only happens  sometimes while gaming or at random times for a sec or 2. I'll try to reproduce it with an open case to see if i can better isolate where the sound is coming from and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: Found the issue (or so i hope), it seems like the GPU case is buzzing. I updated my question, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer would be: You need to do something that stops it from vibrating.

Maybe something that could serve as a support "column" from underneath and up that could align it perfectly.

```
======
     |  <- column
------
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with more of a thudding noise coming from my power supply, it turned out to be cords from my graphics card hanging down, make sure to check and make sure the fan is clear

Comment: This was already covered in the accepted answer.