# PSU is making a weird noise

Tags: hardware-failure

I'll tell you the story of how I started to notice the problem with my PSU. I was just playing some minecraft, just doing my thing when I started to hear a strange buzzing noise from my PC. So i opened it up to so what was up. I couldn't clearly hear where the noise was coming from. So I took off both of the side panels and heard it was coming from the PSU.

After this I started looking up online for what this might be. At this point I should tell you my hardware. I'm running an RTX 2080 and I5-9600k with my PSU being a 750W MasterWatt from coolermaster.

I came across this post from Dante R. [Weird buzzing noise coming from the pc (PSU perhaps)](https://superuser.com/questions/1387689/weird-buzzing-noise-coming-from-the-pc-psu-perhaps)

I thought, hey this guy has the same GPU as me. He might have the solution. But in his post the problem was with the GPU, not the PSU. So I went back to checking if it indeed was my GPU. But after listening closely I could clearly hear it was coming from my PSU. (Which is why I posted this Question since the other post was fixed by fixing the GPU)

Here is a video so you can get an idea of what it sounds like. https://youtu.be/V7XiBgKpkdY

Afterwards I did some testing as to why it only started when I was playing Minecraft. I loaded up Prime95 to do some CPU stress testing... no noise. I launched up Heaven Benchmark... As soon as my GPU started doing it's thing, the noise came back! So it has something to do with GPU aswell.

From what I read I think it may have something to do with Coil Whine. And if so,can it be dangerous for my PC and how can I stop it?

So I'm looking for any advice you lovely people can give me on how to stop this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it dangerous?  In the short to medium term, no. Longer term the PSU may or may not fail.  Can you do anything to stop it?  Not likely except to replace the PSU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That just sounds like normal fan noise to me. It's regular, not *too* loud and just sounds a lot like a fan under PWM control. For normal noises you can expect of a fan that is working there's [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jplQqsP7sPk). Notice the loud "whine" when the fan is at full speed. Yours certainly is not that.

The reason you see it while running heavy graphics stuff rather than when your CPU is working is because the GPU has a maximum TDP (Thermal Dissipation Power - amount of power dissipated to do its work) [of 215W](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-rtx-2080.c3224) while your i5 [maximum is 95W](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/134896/intel-core-i5-9600k-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-60-ghz.html).

Your GPU is capable of drawing more than twice as much power as your CPU and as a result is demanding a lot more of your PSU. The power drawn causes the power conversion circuitry in your PSU to heat up, and as a result it gets warm. Getting warm triggers thermal control circuitry that in turn controls a fan and this is the noise you are hearing.

That the noise is relatively low frequency is promising. It means that your PSU isn't working *massively* hard. If the noise were high pitched then it would be a sign of the fan working very hard, the PSU overheating and a power supply that is near its limits.

The noise you are hearing could at worst indicate a slightly restricted airflow through the PSU, but a low hum like I could hear in your video is not too bad. If you really want the noise gone then better airflow into the case might help, but probably not significantly.

It is possible that there is a wire in or around the PSU which is causing some of the noise, knocking against the case when the fan makes the PSU vibrate. Again, not a massive problem though.