# Notebook makes peepy noises sporadically

Tags: laptop

I have an only 1 year old `HP ZBook 14u G4`. When it is connected to the power (also tested different power adapters), sporadically peepy noises come from the notebook for about 5-10 seconds. Its in a high frequency that not everybody can hear. I recorded the noise with a good smartphone microphone, feel free to download the [recording](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fham8o6awm2j22u/noises.m4a?dl=0).

What we already tried:

- Replaced the fan
- Replaced the motherboard
- Replaced the speaker

I think it has something to do with the power circulation.
In battery mode, the noise does not come.

Any ideas on how to get rid of this noises?

Comment: Note: Your recording was deleted from `file.io`. The noise might be Coil Whine. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1389226/8672).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks I updated the link to a public dropbox file. Thanks for the hint for Coil Whine, I will look into.